# This exception handling code requires fixing

Tags: c#, .net

This is my current exception handling code.

Take especial note of the line `throw e;` marked with `***`.

```
try
{
  //some code that could cause exception
}
catch (FaultException e) //first catch a particular type of exception only
{
  if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Message, "something")) //satisfying a particular condition
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Particular exception occurred.");
    return;
  }
  else
    throw e; // <-- *** Problem! Not getting caught by the "catch" below.
}
catch (Exception e) //catch all other exceptions
{
  Console.WriteLine("General exception ocurred");
  return;
}
```

The problem is this: If the `throw e; // <-- ***` occurs, it is not getting caught by the final `catch`. Instead, the app just crashes as if the exception was not handled.

How can this be fixed in the simplest possible way?

You see in the first `catch` that I'm only interested in actually handling `FaultException` exceptions satisfying a particular condition, but leave all others (both `FaultException` exceptions **not** satisfying the condition **and** exceptions that are not `FaultException`) to the final `catch`. Unfortunately, this is not working properly.

I'm on .NET 4.

Comment: At first glance I'd say the problem is you are rethrowing the `FaultException` so the base `Exception` catch will never catch it.  Also this is a really really weird thing to want to do. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one `catch` block is executed per `try` block.

I would rewrite the `catch` block as:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e is FaultException && Regex.IsMatch(e.Message, "something"))
    {
        ....
    }
    else // all other exceptions
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what he wanted to do was actually do something if it's a FaultException, and then do something for all Exceptions, even if it's a FaultException - so maybe lose the else.

Comment: Kiyura, note the `return` after `Console.WriteLine("Particular exception occurred.");`

Answer (score 5):

You don't fully understand the try/catch syntax. You can attach multiple catches to a single try - the one that matches most closely is the one that will be selected. In this case, FaultException's catch will fire, and then the more general Exception one will never be called, because the exception has already been handled.

What you need to do is wrap the entire try/catch in another try/catch specifically for the more general Exception case, if you always want to handle that; either that or rework your logic. (For instance, you could just simplify it to be an Exception catch and then check if it's a FaultException.)

Answer (score 1):

The `throw e` will never be `caught` by exception catches at the same level.

A `throw` inside of a `catch`, will **always** throw to the invoker of the method.

Also, its recommended that if you want to re-throw do `throw` instead of `throw e`.  The first case preserves the call-stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception within a catch block, it won't be caught within the same try-catch.

You could repeat in the else condition what you're doing in the other catch block (not too bad in this specific case).